# MBP, El Capitan - Keyboard not working, but I can get to safe mode?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, macos, startup, safe-mode

My keyboard is currently not working (literally nothing appears on a password screen when I start typing, both in safe mode and in normal mode). I am currently typing this on an external keyboard. I have tried:

- NVRAM reset
- SMC reset
- Removing the password from the password screen
- Trying another user account, no go.
- I would really prefer not to wipe the system.

I just want to know if this is a hardware thing or just a software one. I would like to believe that it's just software because I can get to safe mode (pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>), do NVRAM reset (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>P</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>), and get to the recovery partitions all on the internal keyboard.

How can I fix this?

Update: Hardware diagnostics (pressing <kbd>D</kbd> on the internal keyboard whens starting the machine) did not find something wrong with they keyboard

Update: I don't think this is a duplicate of [Keyboard key stuck or not being recognized; how to fix](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/298853/keyboard-key-stuck-or-not-being-recognized-how-to-fix) as I am able to boot to recovery/safe mode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keyboard key stuck or not being recognized; how to fix](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/298853/keyboard-key-stuck-or-not-being-recognized-how-to-fix)

Comment: Since you can boot to other modes that require keyboard commands, there's a good change it's software based. But to help confirm, if you boot to recovery mode (hold Command-R while booting)  you should be able to open a terminal application from the menu. Do all of your letters and numbers output?

Comment: @moneyt no keys work in recovery mode. :(

Answer (score 1):

Since the hardware diagnostics test did not find anything wrong with the keyboard, this is more than likely a software glitch.

Take your laptop into an Apple Store, they always help out with things like this.