# The play/pause and backward and forward buttons on my MacBook are not working properly

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, audio, high-sierra

The play/pause and backward and forward buttons on my MacBook are not working as they should. When I press the play/pause button, nothing happens or it quickly pauses and plays again. Backward/Forward buttons are skipping previous/next song and play the second one in order.

I don't have Google Play Music installed. I've also reset SMC but it didn't help.

Anyone know what could be a possible problem?

I'm using macOS High Sierra.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZFZM.jpg

Comment: To see if it's a hardware issue, assign F8 a particular function.  Then, press Fn+F8 to see if it works.  If not, then it's possibly hardware.  See this post:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/298853/keyboard-key-stuck-or-not-being-recognized-how-to-fix

Comment: The key is working so any other ideas what can be a problem ?

Comment: are those media keys bound to anything?  I use Vox media player and it has the ability to hind to those keys making the “unavailable” to other apps.

Comment: @Allan that's what happening https://imgur.com/a/VoY3w I don't have any special program that could use these keys.