# I need to disable my main keyboard as one letter is not working and it's out of warranty

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

This is my current setup:

[image]

- 1 year warranty expired.
- 90 days warranty warranty expired too.
- Using external keyboard on top of the internal keyboard for now.
- I need to disable the built-in one, because using the external keyboard sometimes triggers keystrokes from the internal keyboard.
- Alternatively, I can rebind some key to act as `r`

I am looking for a temporary software solution; in particular something [like this](https://lifehacker.com/236631/download-of-the-day-keyboard-cleaner-mac), but it should lock the keyboard instead of disabling the screen.

Comment: Why do you have to lock it? Can't you just ignore it since you are not using it? There probably is a program that could find something unused like an fkey to a normal keystroke, but it would likely be slower than a regular keystroke. So high speed typing might not go smooth, and you could even get out of order letters.

Comment: "lock it" so that no keypresses are recorded as I'm typing on an external keyboard.

Comment: Rebinding some key to act as r can be done using the apps Ukelele or Karabiner.

Comment: Hardware solution alternative: [*The Roost Stand*](https://www.therooststand.com) to elevate the laptop while using keyboard/mouse separately.

Comment: So the `r` isn't working on the original keyboard? Have you tried taking the key off and seeing whether you can fix it?

Comment: I don't like hacks that remap keys, because (especially in this case), you won't be able to reset the NVRAM or boot to recovery.  I suggest you fix it.  [The fix is actually not that difficult.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/298853/keyboard-key-stuck-or-not-being-recognized-how-to-fix).  It's just time consuming.

Comment: He has to lock it because he is resting the replacement keyboard on the old keyboard. Another reason to want it locked would be if keys on the original keyboard were stuck pressed.

Comment: If you have a decent Mac-savvy repair shop nearby they can easily do it.  Mine swapped in a used keyboard from someone else's machine.  Still works, 3 years later and cost me less than $100.  A laptop with an external keyboard is not much of a laptop.

Comment: Unrelated, but as you're in the UK, you might be covered under the EU 2 year consumer electronics warranty, rather than the included 1 year warranty. It might be worth a check.

Comment: Id like to add that my MBP is a 2011 so what's fixable on it may not be so on recent MBPs. The lack of aftermarket and repairability on recent MBPs are even more dissuasive to me than their price.

Answer (score 31):

You can disable the keyboard by unloading the kernel extension with

```
sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleUSBTopCase.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleUSBTCKeyboard.kext/
```

To reload,

```
sudo kextload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleUSBTopCase.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleUSBTCKeyboard.kext/
```

You didn't say what version of macOS you are using, I believe this syntax works as of 10.10. Some tweaking may be needed depending on your version.

Answer (score 24):

Actually you can buy replacement keyboards online, at the very least eBay has a number of them on sale. Have a look at ifixit.com as they show how to do it and it should be able to give you an idea if you will be able to replace it yourself.

The insides of MacBooks can be a bit fiddly but with a little care and the right tools (which ifixit sells) you can probably do it yourself.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question- the OP wants to *disable* their keyboard. *not* buy a new one. MacBook keyboards are also **extremely** difficult to replace due to how Apple mounts the keyboard to the case, and certainly isn't something your average joe will be able to do.

Comment: One thing I have learned in supporting computers over the years is that it is important to also answer the question that they didn't ask as an *option* in case they did not consider an option that they did not think of or think was possible. And one person's **extremely** difficult is another person's "a bit fiddly."

Comment: It's called the XYProblem: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: @cybermonkey The fact that the OP mentions expired warranties suggests they _would_ have liked it fixed if feasible (but presumably not at the price Apple would charge).

Comment: @SteveChambers Yes... but this is a Q&A site and you are expected to be general and not just solve the OP's problem. I think it's pretty clear from the question that the OP does not have the time and/or money to purchase a replacement keyboard. Oh, and by `extremely difficult` I really *do* mean difficult- Rossman even says that it's a complete pain to replace.

Comment: @cybermonkey Consider letting the voting system do its job...

Comment: This provides an answer to the original question. If this procedure is followed the keyboard shown in OP's screenshot will be disabled in a way much more definitive than with a software command since it will be **removed** from the laptop.

Comment: I can't up vote this enough. I simply don't understand the need to "bodge" quick fixes together rather than address and fix the actual problem.

Comment: This is NOT an answer. Judging by the photo, OP is using a 2016-2017 MBP. The keyboards on these models are generally not replaceable, even by trained professionals (see iFixit's teardown on this model).

Comment: I should add - I certainly like the idea of a permanent hardware fix, but I think replacing a keyboard on the current model MBP is a _highly_ risky thing to attempt.

Comment: ifixit sells really overpriced tools. If I were you, I would first check if I could find something reasonable elsewhere.

Comment: Are you serious? Are you really suggesting me fiddling with keyboard? https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Touch+Bar+Teardown/73395 - repairability score 1 out of 10. I do not know what I wrote in the original question, after edits it says `I am looking for a temporary software solution` - suggestion that I should replace keyboard is not cool.

Answer (score 21):

The easiest way is to install "[Karabiner Elements](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/)".

Once it is installed open the "Preferences" from the menu on the right of your menu bar.

[image]

Now in the bottom half of the pane you can now choose to disable the builtin keyboard when your other keyboard is connected.

BTW - you can also use Karabiner Elements to map another key combination to do the same as the broken one, such as <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>option</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> to <kbd>s</kbd>. I did this for quite a while with a broken "\" key on a MacBook Pro.

Comment: "easiest" is subjective. This is a way to do it through a graphical interface.

Answer (score 6):

## Karabiner

via [Tom Gewecke](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/49804/tom-gewecke)

[image]

I'm not a hardware guy, I may use unofficial service or gadget insurance.

Comment: This does not count as an answer to the question as it is link-only. Instead, please expand your answer explaining the steps to disable or rebind keys using Karabiner.

Comment: @cybermonkey: This isn’t link-only at all!  “A picture is worth a thousand words”: this screenshot shows as much as several paragraphs of text would about what Karabiner is and how to rebind keys with it.

Comment: @PLL The screenshot does not explain how to add the keybind, if I used Karabiner I wouldn't be able to set-up the appropiate keybind using that screenshot as a guide.

Comment: @cybermonkey - `please expand your answer explaining the steps` - The app is so simple. Screenshot shows exactly where to click. What do you mean?

Comment: @MichalStefanow It may seem simple to you, but to others it may not be. Please remember that you're answering the Q&A and that anyone can have the same question and follow the steps provided in an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Karabiner Elements as another user suggested will do exactly what you want, but have you tried taking it to the Apple store anyway? They often repair out-of-warranty, especially for a recent device like your 2016 Mac, and sometimes even for free. Also the keyboard failures are a bit of a common issue so they probably have some in stock.

Answer (score 0):

### KeyboardCleanTool

This application will lock your keyboard once you open it and press the "Lock the keyboard" button. It is not meant for locking the keyboard permanently, but might be useful.