# Restart. Some updates. Mac does not start anymore. Logs attached. How to fix it?

Tags: auto-update

[image]

```
Apr 19 21:50:04 MacBook-Pro ReportCrash[553]: Process:               macOS Installer [549]
Apr 19 21:50:04 MacBook-Pro ReportCrash[553]: Path:                  /System/Installation/CDIS/macOS Installer.app/Contents/MacOS/macOS Installer
Apr 19 21:50:04 MacBook-Pro ReportCrash[553]: Identifier:            com.apple.macOS-Installer
Apr 19 21:50:04 MacBook-Pro ReportCrash[553]: Version:               1.0 (1004.29)
Apr 19 21:50:04 MacBook-Pro ReportCrash[553]: Build Info:            OSInstaller-1004029000000000~86
Apr 19 21:50:04 MacBook-Pro ReportCrash[553]: Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Apr 19 21:50:04 MacBook-Pro ReportCrash[553]: Parent Process:        ??? [527]
Apr 19 21:50:04 MacBook-Pro ReportCrash[553]: Responsible:           macOS Installer [549]
Apr 19 21:50:04 MacBook-Pro ReportCrash[553]: User ID:               0
Apr 19 21:50:04 MacBook-Pro ReportCrash[553]:  
Apr 19 21:50:04 MacBook-Pro ReportCrash[553]: Date/Time:             2018-04-19 14:49:54.196 -0700
Apr 19 21:50:04 MacBook-Pro ReportCrash[553]: OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.13.4 (17E199)
Apr 19 21:50:04 MacBook-Pro ReportCrash[553]: Report Version:        12
Apr 19 21:50:04 MacBook-Pro ReportCrash[553]: Bridge OS Version:     <device not connected>
Apr 19 21:50:04 MacBook-Pro ReportCrash[553]: Anonymous UUID:        FB9E7040-D694-4666-932D-0596AA936FC4
Apr 19 21:50:04 MacBook-Pro ReportCrash[553]:  
Apr 19 21:50:04 MacBook-Pro ReportCrash[553]:  
Apr 19 21:50:04 MacBook-Pro ReportCrash[553]: Time Awake Since Boot: 79 seconds
Apr 19 21:50:04 MacBook-Pro ReportCrash[553]:  
Apr 19 21:50:04 MacBook-Pro ReportCrash[553]: System Integrity Protection: disabled
Apr 19 21:50:04 MacBook-Pro ReportCrash[553]:  
Apr 19 21:50:04 MacBook-Pro ReportCrash[553]: Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Apr 19 21:50:04 MacBook-Pro ReportCrash[553]:  
Apr 19 21:50:04 MacBook-Pro ReportCrash[553]: Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Apr 19 21:50:04 MacBook-Pro ReportCrash[553]: Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000018
Apr 19 21:50:04 MacBook-Pro ReportCrash[553]: Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Apr 19 21:50:04 MacBook-Pro ReportCrash[553]:  
Apr 19 21:50:04 MacBook-Pro ReportCrash[553]: Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Apr 19 21:50:04 MacBook-Pro ReportCrash[553]: Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Apr 19 21:50:04 MacBook-Pro ReportCrash[553]: Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]
```

## Full log on Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/GtkESaWh

Any ideas?

Comment: Just experienced this with Mac OS 10.13.6 on a brand new MacBool Pro, and I was fortunate enough to be able to restore from the local time machine backup that the system is making automatically

Comment: Did you fix this? I have the same issue.

Comment: Don't remember :(

Answer (score 2):

The crash report blames the installer, so the installer ran into a situation it could not cope with.

Can you boot into safe mode (<kbd>Shift</kbd>) during startup? If so download the combo update for 10.13.4 and run that.

If not, then the *big* question is can you boot into recovery mode (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>r</kbd>) at startup?

If you can I would first run disk utility and see if it can **repair** the disk. If it reports errors that can't be fixed, you have a problem as I am not aware of any 3rd-party disk repair utilities that can repair APFS disks (anyone?).

Please tell me you have a current backup that you can restore from?

If not I would be tempted to take it to an Apple Store and see if they can do anything with the drive.

If Disk Utility can fix or finds no issues, I would reinstall MacOS from Recovery Mode. It **shoudn't** wipe any of your files but depending on what happened I could not guarantee that.

That should get you started.

Comment: I clicked some buttons, startup disk, managed to boot the machine... I have another issue: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/322176/i-need-to-disable-my-main-keyboard-as-one-letter-is-not-working-and-its-out-of I'll probably just sell it and buy a new one with larger storage for all the blockchain operations and virtual machines. `256GB` is a joke, it shouldn't be allowed.

Comment: The safe mode (shift) boot tip worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This happened to a colleague the other day.

**Solution:**

1. Hold `Shift` key during boot to enter Safe Mode.
2. Log in (whilst still in Safe Mode) and run OSX Updates

If you're lucky an OSX Security Update or similar will be waiting for you. Basically any OSX update that requires a reboot should do (fingers crossed) as it rewrites the broken update process.

**Cause:**

OSX Update process failed to execute properly. This could be due to power failure / file corruption. Overwriting the reboot/install process with another one fixes it.