# Is this just a keyboard defect or more

Tags: keyboard, repair, macbook-pro, hardware

I was stupidly trying to clean the keyboard by taking out each key using a screwdriver as a lever, washing and subsequently drying them. Now only the power button works (MBA 2012). During the process, the screwdriver pierced through some of the plastic "button" (which in itself shouldn't be a problem I guess), and the sharp head (not always dry) touched the underlying board (which is not the motherboard) from time to time as well.

Now I'm planning to replace the broken part on my own, and found out two options. Either the keyboard alone, which isn't officially supported but cheaper, or the complete upper case. For the first option I'd need to make sure that it's really just the keyboard that's broken. Could anyone tell me roughly how likely it is the case from my description?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to post a picture with a good zoom camera of one to four keys showing the damage caused by the removal? Also, if you’re being honest (and no judgement) - was this effort to replace the keys doomed to not enough training, not the right tools or just that you were impatient and under estimated how delicate things are? Something dramatic would need to change if you broke more than 4 keys before stopping and seeking help. Basically, it’s going to be hard for us to guess how to advise you specifically.

Answer (score 0):

At this point, you know you have a keyboard that's much easier to work on than the new butterfly design and an excellent / detailed explanation how that keyboard works.

- [Keyboard key stuck or not being recognized; how to fix](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/298853/keyboard-key-stuck-or-not-being-recognized-how-to-fix)

Also, you have an appreciation that doing this removal of a key has a very non-zero chance of breaking things. At this point you have a resource dilemma.

- How much is your time worth?
- How many parts and training do you need to successfully re-assemble the physical case?

If you want to fix it yourself, you can test all the keys physically by making sure the nubbin presses. If that's broken - you need a new top case or you need to consider using a bluetooth keyboard (if you must be portable) or a USB keyboard if low cost and low mobility is best.

Next cheapest is trying the top case repair, but you run the risk of under-estimating the tools and training needed there and could also break more than just the keyboard if you attempt a top case transplant of the computer (you're moving all the parts of the computer to a new frame, basically).

Also - consider getting a quote. Apple might charge $300 to repair everything you messed up and everything wrong with the computer functionally and put a 90 day warranty on all the parts touched in the repair. You're basically buying the best used Mac verified by Apple and you know the previous owner. I don't know many people that would turn down that good a deal if they needed a new computer, so don't look back about how cheap this could have been if the repair had only worked. It didn't (for reasons) and you're now faced with what next now that you know DIY repairs might have more risks than apparent at first. *(Also don't undervalue your experience and knowledge you gained in this. I know some of the best repair people started just like you, so with time and training this may teach you more than if the key swap just went well.)*

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The keys function physically as well as before. The only apparent physical damage are on some of the nubbins. It was due partly to my impatience and partly to the insufficient training that I've messed things up. I was reading this guide http://www.insidemylaptop.com/replacing-macbook-air-keyboard-after-liquid-damage/ when I found out I might have another solution between the first and second one you suggested. But Apple is out of the question and I'm prepared to invest much time into it and gain more experience out of it since I have another better macbook.

Comment: Wonderful @Andrew. I worked professionally as a repair technician and know you can get away with super gluing the nubbins on when they are damaged - slice them off entirely in some cases and then gluing is better than having them half cut. Of course that's a point of no return - if the glue fails - you won't get that key working again in all likelihood. Good luck and see how many of the keys you can revive knowing you can always use an external KB.

Comment: But the more serious problem is that digitally, the laptop doesn't react to key presses. I don't think the nubbins have to do with that?