# Cleaning the membrane side of an unresponsive key? (MBP Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014)

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, macos

I've got an MBP Retina Mid 2014.  The "f" key has become [recalcitrant](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/recalcitrant) and usually takes several forceful presses to make it respond.  I've already removed the keytop and its carrier and cleaned out the lint that surrounded them.  Though there was a lot of lint, that didn't solve the problem.

While the keytop was removed, I tried pushing down on the silicone 'nub' at the center of the key and noticed that the response was still intermittent.

This led me to believe that the problem is on the *bottom* of the silicone membrane.  While there are many online guides on how to clean out the *top* of the keyboard, there are relatively few reputable guides to cleaning the *bottom* side.

Given that I have a set of pentalobe drivers and a steady hand:

- where can I find dependable instructions on cleaning the bottom side of the keyboard (i.e. where the keytop makes electrical contact with the bottom)?
- how much does an entire replacement keyboard cost (if I choose to go that route... :)?

Comment: See this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/298853/keyboard-key-stuck-or-not-being-recognized-how-to-fix/298854?s=1|54.9717#298854) regarding the membrane and a [replacement keyboard](https://amzn.to/2JUlpdT) will run you about $30 USD

Comment: Works for me -- do you want to recast your comment as an answer?