# Is Apple using the updated 2018 MacBook Pro keyboard when replacing older keyboards under the new keyboard service program?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, repair

Apple revealed an updated 2018 MacBook Pro with an updated butterfly keyboard. I recently had my 2016 MacBook Pro keyboard replaced under the keyboard service program that was recently opened. Is Apple replacing older keyboards with the new keyboards under the keyboard service program?

Comment: I just compared my newly replaced keyboard to this Techcrunch video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RMyJlJV7XdI, and although it was just replaced, it sounds like the old one to me. Hopefully its a revision of the old one that doesn't fail as often, or at all.

Comment: Updated canonical question/answer:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/298853/119271

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Nope**, sadly not.

[From here](https://www.macrumors.com/2018/07/15/third-gen-keyboard-exclusive-to-2018-macbook-pro/):

> Apple has been servicing affected keyboards free of charge, with the
>   process involving the replacement of one or more keys, or the whole
>   keyboard. For the MacBook Pro, the replacements are second-generation
>   keyboards -- often the 2017 variant with slightly different markings
>   on the Control and Option keys.
>
> When asked if Apple Stores and Apple Authorized Service Providers will
>   be permitted to replace second-generation keyboards on 2016 and 2017
>   MacBook Pro models with the new third-generation keyboards, if
>   necessary, Apple said, no, the third-generation keyboards are
>   exclusive to the 2018 MacBook Pro.

Comment: These “keyboard repairs” are more like a hermit crab getting an entirely new shell and not just repairing one or all the keys. It’s a pretty major operation in almost all cases.

Comment: They replace the entire *top case assembly* which is supposedly different for the 2018 model.  Now, why they can't use the 3rd gen keyboard *pieces/parts* in the 2106/17 models remains a mystery.

Answer (score 1):

This tangentially answers the question but not directly.  @JBis's answer is a better answer to the question, my answer provides supporting info.

---

Teardowns on the new 2018 MBPs have started.  [iFixIt has posted their analysis](https://ifixit.org/blog/10279/apple-macbook-keyboard-cover-up/) and an image of the keyboard.

Apple is calling this "the new 3rd-generation keyboard".  It appears to be the same as the 2nd-gen keyboard with the addition of a thin, rubberized membrane under the keycap.

[image]

In an [interview with The Verge](https://www.theverge.com/2018/7/12/17563640/apple-macbook-pro-touchbar-2018-intel-processor-siri-true-tone), Apple also stated "this new third-generation keyboard wasn’t designed to solve those [dust] issues.”

iFixIt will continue its teardown of the new MBPs and will post more info in the coming weeks.  This membrane will help make the keyboard quieter, at least, and hopefully address some of the failure issues.

Comment: I’m not sure why this got a couple down votes out of the gate. It’s clearly an answer and helps with information that the asker might benefit from knowing.

Comment: Thanks, @bmike.  I probably wasn't clear enough in my answer by directly addressing if the older MBPs get the same keyboard as the 2018 version.  I can see how I can edit it to improve the answer.

Comment: Yes, what does this answer have to do with Apple's policy on replacing older keyboards?

Comment: @TomGewecke I already acknowledged the problem with my answer and my need to improve it.  I'm not sure as to the purpose of your comment; can you please clarify?

Comment: I don't see how you could edit it to make it answer the question.  Perhaps clarify your purpose by putting in a preface like "This doesn't relate to the question of Apple's replacement policy, but has info that the asker and others might benefit from knowing."

Comment: Yeah, there's nothing factually inaccurate here but there's nothing here relating to the question, which is whether the new keyboards will be used with 2016/2017 laptops.