# My keyboard isn’t working and I can’t log into my laptop

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, bluetooth, screen-lock

My sister recently spilled water on my MacBook Air's keyboard, and unfortunately I couldn’t save it. Some keys on my keyboard don’t work, like for example the half the numbers and some letters. Because of this I can’t type in my password since it requires some of the affected keys. I tried to connect my wireless keyboard but my Mac's not detecting it, even though I’ve connected it before. There’s no cable opening on the keyboard either so I can use a wire. Is there another way I can connect my keyboard to my laptop? Or is my laptop just totally done for?

Comment: What do you mean by, "There’s no cable opening on the keyboard either so I can use a wire?" All Macbook Airs have a USB port. Get a cheap USB keyboard.

Comment: Exactly what keys do not work?  If 789uiojkl, your problem may be having Mouse Keys turned on in Accessibility prefs.

Answer (score 2):

Plug in any USB keyboard to the USB port.

- Newest MacBook Air use USB-C connectors (ThunderBolt 3)
- The rest use USB-A

Both work with any PC keyboard or Mac keyboard or whatever usb keyboard you might have around.

Hopefully the liquid damage didn’t break the USB controller or the system board. Your keyboard might be fine and the problem is no keyboard would work. If you reset your SMC once and external keyboard do not work, send your Mac in for data transfer or repair.

Here is a masterpiece on keyboards written by one of our resident experts.

- [Keyboard key stuck or not being recognized; how to fix](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/298853/keyboard-key-stuck-or-not-being-recognized-how-to-fix)

Comment: and if it won't respond to the keyboard?

Comment: ***Hopefully the liquid damage didn’t break the USB controller or the system board.*** @Michael