# Constant beeping and erasing words, not typing after hours of use (MacBook Pro 13-inch, 2017, four thunderbolt 3 ports)

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, hardware

I have a five-year old 2017 MacBook Pro with 8 GB of RAM. After hours of use, and never on startup, my MBP continuously beeps, and it does not stop for several minutes.

While it is beeping, I can't use my keyboard (I have an external mechanical keyboard, a Keychron K4, in case it is the keyboard malfunctioning - some of the keys are giving in, I think it's the switches). Worse yet, it starts erasing words and lines and paragraphs very rapidly in important Word documents I am working on!!

I have to save immediately, close, and then restart otherwise it will delete the entire document.

When I restart, I have to fix what I lost.

What could be causing this malfunction and how do I fix it?

Comment: What happens if you remove the external keyboard?

Comment: I have never tried that...I will do that now and I'll test it out for a couple days to see if it makes a difference. I appreciate the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

> it starts erasing words and lines and paragraphs very rapidly in important Word documents I am working on.

This is symptomatic of a failing keyboard.  It is likely the [keys are becoming stuck](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/298853/119271) and filling up the buffer to the point it’s full; this explains the beeping.  The erasing of words and lines could be the Backspace or Delete key being held.

Remove your external keyboard. If the problem no longer persists, the keyboard is at fault. If not, you likely have an issue with the built in keyboard.

As a Keychron user myself, the switches are replaceable. If you narrow it down to this keyboard, the good news is you can fix it easily and inexpensively

Comment: Thank you so much, this is incredibly helpful. I realize now that my keyboard cmd c keys haven't been working right lately and I've had to restart my computer several times because of that. Coupled with your answer, it's now clear to me this is a keyoard and not a computer issue.I am really grateful for your answer and for this forum, without it, I would be so lost.